# matching multiple object using OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, template-matching

I am trying to match multiple object using only one template. 
But the problem is my program is matching multiple occurance for evrey object in the input image.
How do i match multiple objects and evrey objects for just one time in the input image?

**This is my code**

```
public void run(String inFile, String templateFile, String outFile, int match_method) {
    System.out.println("\nRunning Template Matching");

    Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(inFile);
    Mat templ = Imgcodecs.imread(templateFile);

    // / Create the result matrix
    int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
    Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    // / Do the Matching and Normalize
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
    Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

    while(true)
    {
    // / Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
    Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

    Point matchLoc;
    if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
        matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
    } else {
        matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    }      

        if(mmr.maxVal >=0.97)
         {
            // / Show me what you got
            Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, 
                new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), 
                new    Scalar(0,255,0),2);
            //Imgproc.putText(img, "Edited by me",
              //  new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),matchLoc.y + templ.rows()),
                //Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0 ,new  Scalar(0,255,255));
            Imgproc.rectangle(result, matchLoc, 
                new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), 
                new    Scalar(0,255,0),-1);                 
         }
         else
         {
             break; //No more results within tolerance, break search
         }
    }

    // / Show me what you got
    //Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(), 
    //matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),2);

    // Save the visualized detection.
    System.out.println("Writing "+ outFile);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(outFile, img);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java310");
    run("test.jpg", "temp.png",  "output.png", Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
}
```

**test.jpg**

[image]
**temp.png**

[image]

**the result**
[image]

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need non-maximum suppression step.

Something like this: [NMS for python 1](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/) or faster version [NMS for python 2](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/16/faster-non-maximum-suppression-python/).